# SinonJS: calledWith() with exact object

Tags: angular, unit-testing, sinon

I am trying to test that a spy in my Sinon tests is being called with an exact object: no missing properties, no additional properties and no changed properties.

I have this:

```
assert( viewer.entities.add.calledWith( completeEntityObject ) );
```

but if I omit some properties from `completeEntityObject`, the test succeeds. I would like it to fail. I would like a deep comparison.

I have tried looking at the `sinon.match` methods but, although there are tests for arrays being deeply equal, there is no such test for objects. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You can try to use  [ng-test-runner](https://github.com/Pragmatists/ng-test-runner) to test http communication in angular component. [Example from documentation](https://github.com/Pragmatists/ng-test-runner/wiki/Testing-HTTP-interactions#example). Testing http communication in that library uses SinonJS but has nicer api then plain SinonJS.

Comment: That's not exactly what I was after, but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone looking for how to assert that your sinon spy was called with certain arguments, here's a simple example.

```js
  const spy = sinon.spy();

  // If spy is ever called in your code with some arguments, like so:
  spy({ hello: 'world'});

  // You can assert for it in your tests like this:
  expect(spy.getCall(0).calledWith(sinon.match({ hello: 'world' }))).to.be.true;

  // Breaking this down a bit:
  // spy.getCall(0) gives us the first time our spy function was called (because it can be called more than once)

  // Bonus: While debugging, you can use spy.getCalls()[0].args[0] to get the arguments that your spy function was called with.
```

I hope this is helpful - this is my first SO reply so forgive me if I break rules, or haven't explained things in detail.

Answer (score -3):

I found the solution. I used this:

```
sinon.assert.calledWith( addStub, sinon.match( cesiumPartialEntityObject ) );
```

This fails if there are missing or additional properties.

Comment: Can you explain? Or pass some links?

Comment: @VladimirVukanac I've posted an example below in case it is helpful.

Comment: This solution is incorrect, `sinon.match(object)`, according to the documentation, `Requires the value to be not null or undefined and have at least the same properties as expectation.` It does not ensure that there are "no missing properties, no additional properties and no changed properties." , as your question mentions.

Sinon documentation: https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/matchers/